# Callback function running inside object context?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm trying to configure an object at runtime passing a callback function like so:

```
class myObject{
  protected $property;
  protected $anotherProperty;

  public function configure($callback){
    if(is_callable($callback)){
      $callback();
    }
  }
}

$myObject = new myObject(); //
$myObject->configure(function(){
  $this->property = 'value';
  $this->anotherProperty = 'anotherValue';
});
```

Of course I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

My question is if there is a way to achieve this behavior using `$this` inside a callback function or maybe get a suggestion for a better pattern.

PS: I prefer to use a callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with your idea, you could pass `$this` as a parameter to your callback

But note that **your callback** *(which is not declared inside your class)* **will not be able to access protected nor private properties/methods** -- which means you'll have to set up public methods to access those.

Your class would then look like this :

```
class myObject {
  protected $property;
  protected $anotherProperty;
  public function configure($callback){
    if(is_callable($callback)){
      // Pass $this as a parameter to the callback
      $callback($this);
    }
  }
  public function setProperty($a) {
    $this->property = $a;
  }
  public function setAnotherProperty($a) {
    $this->anotherProperty = $a;
  }
}
```

And you'd declared you callback, and use it, like this :

```
$myObject = new myObject(); //
$myObject->configure(function($obj) {
  // You cannot access protected/private properties or methods
  // => You have to use setters / getters
  $obj->setProperty('value');
  $obj->setAnotherProperty('anotherValue');
});
```

Calling the following line of code just after :

```
var_dump($myObject);
```

Would output this :

```
object(myObject)[1]
  protected 'property' => string 'value' (length=5)
  protected 'anotherProperty' => string 'anotherValue' (length=12)
```

Which shows that the callback has been executed, and the properties of your object have indeed been set, as expected.

Comment: +1 This is a good step forward. I'm going to wait for a possible better answer for a while, before accept.

Comment: can you please describe the work flow of this code? there are some things there that I can't understand...I want to fully understand this...does $this inside $callback($this) gonna be $callback($this, 'func')? thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using (or are willing to upgrade to) PHP 5.4, you can the new [`bindTo`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) method of [Closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).  This allows you to "re-bind" a closure to a new scope.

Before calling `$callback`, you can set its `$this` to what you want.

```
if(is_callable($callback)){
    $callback = $callback->bindTo($this, $this);
    $callback();
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lRWHTn

You can also use `bindTo` outside of the class.

```
$func = function(){
  $this->property = 'value';
  $this->anotherProperty = 'anotherValue';
};
$myObject->configure($func->bindTo($myObject, $myObject));
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mNgMDz

Comment: +1 That's one additional reason to upgrade PHP to its latest version ;-)

Comment: +1 this is a great answer, but unfortunately I have to keep the code compatible with PHP5.3.* (all add the 5.3 tag)

Comment: @marcioAlmada: I'll leave this here anyway. :-P